# What's up with the [usage] tag?

Tags: support, bug, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) redirects to [word-usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage), as [the two are synonymized](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/word-usage/synonyms).

But I can still find the tag on certain questions.

When I search for the [word-usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) tag, many of the earlier results still display that tag. Here's a screenshot of a few of many:

> [image]

- [Why is "protested over" incorrect in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211798/why-is-protested-over-incorrect-in-this-sentence)
- [Why does 'up' have a positive connotation and 'down' have a negative connotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211654/why-does-up-have-a-positive-connotation-and-down-have-a-negative-connotation)
- [In At vs In From vs Into](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211548/in-at-vs-in-from-vs-into) [has both!]
- ["In the immortal words of..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211504/in-the-immortal-words-of)

I don't think this is typical behavior for a synonymized tag; what's going on? Why does the [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) tag still linger on some of the older questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was just some moderator housekeeping work to be done yet. We almost never remember to ask the system about which ones need merging, let alone do so. I've taken care of that now.

Comment: I was the one who created the synonym (I think) and I didn't do a full merge in case we wanted to reverse it.